# vuejs - Redirect from login/register to home if already loggedin, Redirect from other pages to login if not loggedin in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to redirect user to home page if logged-in and wants to access login/register page and redirect user to login page if not logged-in and wants to access other pages. Some pages are excluded that means there is no need to be logged in so my code is right below:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(
        to.name == 'About' ||
        to.name == 'ContactUs' ||
        to.name == 'Terms'
    )
    {
        next();
    }
    else
    {
        axios.get('/already-loggedin')
            .then(response => {
                // response.data is true or false
                if(response.data)
                {
                    if(to.name == 'Login' || to.name == 'Register')
                    {
                        next({name: 'Home'});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        next();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    next({name: 'Login'});
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // console.log(error);
            });
    }
});
```

But the problem is that it gets into an infinite loop and for example each time login page loads and user not logged-in, it redirects user to login page and again to login page and...

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should trying use `else` blocks in your `then()`.  I don't think `next` exists the function.

Comment: As I know when next function executes it doesn't continue anymore. it is just like return. However I did that either but no result :(

Comment: did you try `router.push('Home')` instead of  `next({name: 'Home'});``?

Comment: No I didn't. You mean it might not declared route named 'Home'? It is.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's what I'm doing. First I'm using a `meta` data for the routes, so I don't need to manually put all routes that are not requiring login:

```js
routes: [
  {
    name: 'About' // + path, component, etc
  },
  {
    name: 'Dashboard', // + path, component, etc
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]
```

Then, I have a global guard like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next({ name: 'Login' })
    } else {
      next() // go to wherever I'm going
    }
  } else {
    next() // does not require auth, make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```

Here I am storing if the user is logged in or not, and not making a new request.

In your example, you have **forgotten** to include `Login` into the list of pages that "don't need authentication". So if the user is trying to go to let's say `Dashboard`, you make the request, turns out he's not logged in. Then he goes to `Login`, BUT your code checks, sees it's not part of the 3 "auth not required" list, and makes another call :)

Therefore skipping this "list" is crucial! ;)

Good luck!

Comment: I have checked for login too in order that if the user had logged in he shouldn't see login page nor register page. But if he hadn't he can. But thank you your answer helped me in another way, So I'd like to select it as answer.

Comment: Yeah, but if the user is not logged in, in your case, he can never do it. Glad it worked out!

Comment: Maybe the point is in `response.data` part. The value returned here is true if user has already logged in and false if has not. `Auth::check` in Laravel. So if user has not logged in yet the value of `response.data` will be false and the user will be redirected to login page.

Comment: And on this redirect isn't the guard going to fire again?  And if so - what happens then, in the guard for the Login?

Comment: if he is logged-in and wants to access login page, he is redirected to home page. if he is logged-in and wants to access home page, he can. if he is not logged-in and wants to access login page he can. if he is not logged-in and wants to access home page, he will redirect to login page.

Comment: how do you import `store` in the router.beforeEach method?

Answer (score 17):

If someone is still looking for an answer, you can reverse the logic. So, the same way you have requiresAuth, you will have hidden routes for authenticated users. (example with firebase)

```
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/login',
            meta: {
                hideForAuth: true
            }
        },
         {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        }]
```

And in your beforeEeach

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
            if (!user) {
                next({ path: '/login' });
            } else {
                next();
            }

        } else {
            next();
        }

        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.hideForAuth)) {
            if (user) {
                next({ path: '/dashboard' });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but throwing following error on console "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard."

Comment: idea of reversing logic is a good idea. didn't test the code.
AUTH first is a much better practise then having to explicitly make sure you guard every route.

Answer (score 1):

Derived from the answer @Andrey Popov provided.

I prefer to explicitly disallow a route that doesn't require auth. This prevents accidentally not protecting your routes, i.e. the default case is to redirect to a login page

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name === 'login') {
    next() // login route is always  okay (we could use the requires auth flag below). prevent a redirect loop
  } else if (to.meta && to.meta.requiresAuth === false) {
    next() // requires auth is explicitly set to false
  } else if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    next() // i'm logged in. carry on
  } else {
    next({ name: 'login' }) // always put your redirect as the default case
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic concept for this, use  `redirect:'/dashboard'` this way you can do. you have to define it in your **route list**. like this way. you can ignore `mate: {}`. i used this for different purpose.

```
 routes: [ ....
           {
             path: '/login',
             name: 'login',
             component: LoginView,
             meta:{needAuth:false},
             redirect:'/dashboard'
           },
           {
            path: '/sign-up',
            name: 'sign-up',
            component: SignUpView,
            meta:{needAuth:false},
             redirect:'/dashboard'
          },
            {
             path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: UserDashboard,
            meta:{needAuth:true},
            beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
          }
        ]

  

     function ifAuthenticated  (to, from, next)  {  store.test();
      if (localStorage.getItem("login-token")) { console.log("login done");
       next(); 
       return;
     }
      router.push({  name: 'login' });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Andrey's answer, if you use firebase authentication, need to add onAuthStateChanged around createApp in main.ts.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// requireAuth for those you want to authenticate 
// onlyGuest for  those you don't want to autenticate to open other thing if already 
//   logged in then it's redirect to home

 router.beforeEach((to,from,next)=>{
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuth)){

    if(!store.state.loginUser){
      next({name:'Login'});
    }
    else{
      next();
    }
 }
else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.onlyGuest)) {

    if (store.state.loginUser && store.state.loginUser.token) {
        next({name: "Home"});
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
else{
  next();
}
 });
```

Comment: please add some explanation and reformat your answer

Comment: @pejmankheyri requireAuth and onlyGuest is behave like filters for authenticated and non authenticated routes if still confused kindly ping me at raiahmadfraz@gmail.com