# problem while using the created function in two components at the same time

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my app I have a registred area, when you login successfully a global variable "auth" will take the value loggedin, in my main vue component App.vue I load the header component which include the navbar and the router view
I call the created function in the header component to read the value of "auth"  to show the login link and hide the profile,chat and logout links
I also want to use the sema method in some router views (char and profile) to prevent the user to get acces to them and push the router to the login page when the "auth" variable is not loggedin.
In that case, the App.vue have to run the created function twice, the header component reads correctly the value of "auth" while the router view does not.
Is there any solution to do that? or any alternative to prevent the access to the registred area without login ?

---

update

I have tried vuex and I got this error (Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined)
and the store.state.auth still have the value of false

this is my login component

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'
import EventBus from './EventBus.vue'
  export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      axios.post('users/login', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }).then(res => {
        console.log('user exist ')

        localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
        router.push({ name: 'Profile' })
        this.$store.commit('login') // sets auth to true
        this.emitMethod() 
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message)
        this.error = ('User does not exist ')
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''
      })
    },
    onReset(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        // Reset our form values
        this.email = ''
        this.password = ''

        // Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state
        this.show = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.show = true
        })
      },
    emitMethod () {
      EventBus.$emit('logged-in', 'loggedin')

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import AllIosIcon from 'vue-ionicons/dist/ionicons-ios.js'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

/* eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error"] }] */

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(AllIosIcon)

Vue.use(VueRouter)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
      auth: false
  },
  mutations: {
      login: (state) => state.auth = true,
      logout: (state) => state.auth = false
  }
})

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/products',
    name: 'products',

    component: () => import( '../views/Products.vue')
  },{
    path: '/spareParts',
    name: 'spareParts',

    component: () => import( '../views/SpareParts.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'contact',

    component: () => import( '../views/Contact.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',

    component: () => import( '../views/logIn.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/About',
    name: 'About',

    component: () => import( '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/Profile',
    name: 'Profile',

    component: () => import( '../views/Profile.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/Chat',
    name: 'Chat',

    component: () => import( '../views/Chat.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/Spare1',
    name: 'Spare1',

    component: () => import( '../views/Spare1.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare2',
    name: 'spare2',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare2.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare3',
    name: 'spare3',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare3.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare4',
    name: 'spare4',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare4.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare5',
    name: 'spare5',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare5.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare6',
    name: 'spare6',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare6.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare7',
    name: 'spare7',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare7.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare8',
    name: 'spare8',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare8.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare9',
    name: 'spare9',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare9.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare10',
    name: 'spare10',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare10.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare11',
    name: 'spare11',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare11.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare12',
    name: 'spare12',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare12.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare13',
    name: 'spare13',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare13.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare14',
    name: 'spare14',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare14.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare15',
    name: 'spare15',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare15.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare16',
    name: 'spare16',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare16.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare17',
    name: 'spare17',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare17.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare18',
    name: 'spare18',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare18.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare19',
    name: 'spare19',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare19.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare20',
    name: 'spare20',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare20.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare21',
    name: 'spare21',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare21.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare22',
    name: 'spare22',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare22.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/spare23',
    name: 'spare23',

    component: () => import( '../views/spare23.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/product1',
    name: 'product1',

    component: () => import( '../views/product1.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/freezer',
    name: 'freezer',

    component: () => import( '../views/freezer.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/construction',
    name: 'construction',

    component: () => import( '../views/construction.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/product2',
    name: 'product2',

    component: () => import( '../views/product2.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/earth',
    name: 'earth',

    component: () => import( '../views/earth.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/crawler',
    name: 'crawler',

    component: () => import( '../views/crawler.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/articulated',
    name: 'articulated',

    component: () => import( '../views/articulated.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/wheel',
    name: 'wheel',

    component: () => import( '../views/wheel.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/tractor',
    name: 'tractor',

    component: () => import( '../views/tractor.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/telescopic',
    name: 'telescopic',

    component: () => import( '../views/telescopic.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/loader',
    name: 'loader',

    component: () => import( '../views/loader.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/pipe',
    name: 'pipe',

    component: () => import( '../views/pipe.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/pontoon',
    name: 'pontoon',

    component: () => import( '../views/pontoon.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/duty',
    name: 'duty',

    component: () => import( '../views/duty.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/attachment',
    name: 'attachment',

    component: () => import( '../views/attachment.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/customer',
    name: 'customer',

    component: () => import( '../views/customer.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/side',
    name: 'side',

    component: () => import( '../views/side.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/wine',
    name: 'wine',

    component: () => import( '../views/wine.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/accessories',
    name: 'accessories',

    component: () => import( '../views/accessories.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/hotel',
    name: 'hotel',

    component: () => import( '../views/hotel.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/bakery',
    name: 'bakery',

    component: () => import( '../views/bakery.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/retail',
    name: 'retail',

    component: () => import( '../views/retail.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/industry',
    name: 'industry',

    component: () => import( '../views/industry.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/mining',
    name: 'mining',

    component: () => import( '../views/mining.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/mobile',
    name: 'mobile',

    component: () => import( '../views/mobile.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/material',
    name: 'material',

    component: () => import( '../views/material.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/maritime',
    name: 'maritime',

    component: () => import( '../views/maritime.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/aero',
    name: 'aero',

    component: () => import( '../views/aero.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/gear',
    name: 'gear',

    component: () => import( '../views/gear.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/combust',
    name: 'combust',

    component: () => import( '../views/combust.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/hotelgroup',
    name: 'hotelgroup',

    component: () => import( '../views/hotelgroup.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/deep',
    name: 'deep',

    component: () => import( '../views/deep.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/tower',
    name: 'tower',

    component: () => import( '../views/tower.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/concrete',
    name: 'concrete',

    component: () => import( '../views/concrete.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/problem',
    name: 'problem',

    component: () => import( '../views/problem.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.error(store.state.auth)
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.state.auth) {

    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.


      next({ name: 'login' })

  } else {
    next() // does not require auth, make sure to always call next()!
  }
})



export default router; store
```

---

updated

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import AllIosIcon from 'vue-ionicons/dist/ionicons-ios.js'
import i18n from './i18n'
import store from './router'

Vue.use(AllIosIcon)

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  i18n,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

now I got this error
_this.$store.commit is not a function

Comment: Hi, could you please update your question to be more clear? It might also help if you add some code samples. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653337/vuejs-redirect-from-login-register-to-home-if-already-loggedin-redirect-from/52663166

Comment: The question is, where does your "global variable" `auth` come from? Do you use vuex? Any other state management? Or do you just store it in window?

Comment: I used an Eventbus

Comment: Can you include the section where create your Vue instance? I think you're not injecting the `store` variable to the instance. `const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
})`

Comment: Your exports seems to have an error (where you have defined `store` and `router`). Replace the last line with `export default { store, router };`. Then import them in your `main.js` as `import { store, router } from './router'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is to use `vuex` for state management and `vue-router`'s navigation guards.

Look at the code below to understand how this might be done.

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        auth: false
    },
    mutations: {
        login: (state) => state.auth = true,
        logout: (state) => state.auth = false
    }
})

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            name: 'dashboard',
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login,
            name: 'login',
        },
    ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.state.auth) {
        next({
            path: '/login',
            query: {
                redirectTo: to.path
            }
        })
    }

    next()
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
})
```

What we are doing here is setting up a central source of truth for the auth status of a user. The `beforeEach` navigation guard is run before entering a route. In this case we are checking if the route requires authentication (using the `requiresAuth` metadata). If the route requires authentication and you're not logged in, it will redirect you to a login page.

Your login page, should have logic that logs in the user and sets the authentication state to `true`.

**Login.vue**

```html
<template>
  // ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        login() {
            // login logic here
            // after successful login
            this.$store.commit('login') // sets auth to true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This might involve more process but you end up with better results at the end of the day.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but I got this error (Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined)
and the store.state.auth still have the value of false
I will add my login method to the main question  update it

Comment: Make sure you are injecting the `store` variable when you create your Vue instance.